# Looping input file and find out if line is used

Tags: bash, loops, input, awk, grep

I am using bash to loop through a large input file (contents.txt) that looks like:

```
searchterm1
searchterm2
searchterm3
```

...in an effort to remove search terms from the file if they are not used in a code base. I am trying to use grep and awk, but no success.  I also want to exclude the images and constants directories

```
#/bin/bash
while read a; do
  output=`grep -R $a ../website | grep -v ../website/images | grep -v ../website/constants | grep -v ../website/.git`
  if [ -z "$output" ]
  then echo "$a" >> notneeded.txt
  else echo "$a used $($output | wc -l) times" >> needed.txt
  fi
done < constants.txt
```

The desired effect of this would be two files.  One for showing all of the search terms that are found in the code base(needed.txt), and another for search terms that are not found in the code base(notneeded.txt).

needed.txt

```
   searchterm1 used 4 times
   searchterm3 used 10 times
```

notneeded.txt

```
   searchterm2
```

I've tried awk as well in a similar fashion but I cannot get it to loop and output as desired

Comment: So you are checking if the words in `contents.txt` appear in several files `website`, `website/images`, etc. And those lines appearing should be stores in `needed.txt`, while the others in `notneeded.txt`?

Comment: You got it!  I want to recursively look in the ../website directory, but exclude ../website/images ../website/constants and ../website/.git directories from the search.  The search will go through several thousand files.  The input of contents.txt will have about 40 lines of key terms I want to grep for, so it should loop 40 times.

Comment: Do not check if the output of grep is nonempty.  Instead, you can use the value returned by grep: `if grep -q ...; then ...; else; ...; fi`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but it sounds like you're looking for something like this (assuming no spaces in your file names):

```
awk '
NR==FNR{ terms[$0]; next }
{
    for (term in terms) {
        if ($0 ~ term) {
            hits[term]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (term in terms) {
        if (term in hits) {
            print term " used " hits[term] " times" > "needed.txt"
        }
        else {
            print term > "notneeded.txt"
        }
    } 
}
' constants.txt $( find ../website -type f -print | egrep -v '\.\.\/website\/(images|constants|\.git)' )
```

There's probably some `find` option to make the egrep unnecessary.

Comment: `find ../website \( -name images -prune -o -name constants -prune -o -name .git -prune \) -o -type f`

Comment: There y'go. I figured it was a prune, I just wasn't sure of and was too lazy to look up the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Probably better to write it `find ../website \( -name images -o -name constants -o -name .git \) -prune -o -type f`.

Comment: If I try the original, I get : line 21: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long....... If I replace the last line with: ' constants.txt $( find ../website \( -name images -o -name constants -o -name .git \) -prune -o -type f. – ), then I get:find: –: unknown primary or operator
awk: syntax error at source line 13
 context is
             print term  " used " hits[term] " times" > >>>  needed. <<< txt 
awk: illegal statement at source line 14
awk: syntax error at source line 16

Comment: The syntax error around `needed.` is because I hadn't put the file names inside quotes, I've updated my answer to fix that. Which version of the `find` you use shouldn't matter as resulting list of file names should be the same either way. Try again with the corrected script. It you get an arg list too long again, tell us your awk version. If you're on SOlaris do not use /usr/bin/awk as that's old, broken awk - use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead. Best option - get GNU awk.

Comment: Thanks Ed - this has no errors on it, but it also doesn't print anything.  I am on version "20070501" (thats what comes from awk --version) with OSX Mavericks. I am really not familiar with level of skill, so it could even be a minor syntax issue.  It appears that its just hanging.  I tried this on GNU awk as well with the same effect on a centos box.

Comment: OK, well, go through the normal steps you'd go through to debug a small script (break it down into parts, add print statements, etc,) and I'm sure you'll figure it out.